# How to automatically run a jQuery script, without having to click submit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, submit, live

I am currently working on an online store. I have succeeded in coding a script that calculates a product's price and shows this price on the product page when the user clicks on an 'update price' button. Is there a way of doing this without a submit button? In other words: is there a way to make the price show and update automatically?

(I have not included my .php file because it uses data from a database.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<form action="/" id="updatePrice">
  <h3>Size</h3>
  <select class="form-control" id="sizejquery" name="size">
    <option>A0</option>
    <option>A1</option>
    <option>A2</option>
  </select>
  <h3>Type of paper</h3>
  <select class="form-control" id="paperjquery" name="paper">
    <option>white coated paper</option>
    <option>photo paper</option>
  </select>
  <h3>Quantity</h3>
  <select class="form-control" id="quantityjquery" name="quantity">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="update price">
</form>
<div id="price">
  <h3>$0.00</h3>
</div>

<script>
  // Attach a submit handler to the form
  $("#updatePrice").submit(function(event) {

    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $(this),
      size = $form.find("#sizejquery").val(),
      paper = $form.find("#paperjquery").val(),
      quantity = $form.find("#quantityjquery").val(),
      url = $form.attr("action");

    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post(url, {
      size: size,
      paper: paper,
      quantity: quantity
    });

    // Put the results in a div
    posting.done(function(data) {
      var content = $(data).find("#content");
      $("#price").empty().append(content);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You have a lot of events you can use, you should use the one it goes to your objective, see them [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

You can for example, change a quantity of a product an with keyup() you can do whatever you want like get proce and update it.

Comment: How frequently do you want to run the update?

Comment: @LShetty Good question! I have not really thought about that. I guess I want the price to 'update' when the user loads the page (I think I have to use document ready for that) and when the user changes the select boxes' values.

Comment: I have made another update. For it to work, change the button type to "button" instead of "submit"

Answer (score 0):

Right, so, try the following:

```
$(function() {
  $formBtn = $("#updatePrice").find("input.btn-default");
  $formBtn.on("click", function(event) {
    //all your code (the one you already have) here....

  });

  $(window).on("load", function() {
    $formBtn.trigger("click");
  });

  $("#updatePrice").on("change", ".form-control", function() {
    $formBtn.trigger("click");
  });
});
```

Full code:

```
$(function() {
    $formBtn = $("#updatePrice").find("input.btn-default");
    $formBtn.on("click", function(event) {
        // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();
        // Get some values from elements on the page:
        var $form = $("#updatePrice"),
            size = $form.find("#sizejquery").val(),
            paper = $form.find("#paperjquery").val(),
            quantity = $form.find("#quantityjquery")
            .val(),
            url = $form.attr("action");
        // Send the data using post
        var posting = $.post(url, {
            size: size,
            paper: paper,
            quantity: quantity
        });
        // Put the results in a div
        posting.done(function(data) {
            var content = $(data).find(
                "#content");
            $("#price").empty().append(
                content);
        });
    });
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        $formBtn.trigger("click");
    });
    $("#updatePrice").on("change", ".form-control", function() {
        $formBtn.trigger("click");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I must have done something wrong, because my page now immediately jumps to white. Here is the website: http://www.meulen.me/store.php (click on a product to see the page that would normally display the product information + price).

Comment: @meulendev, not sure what you've done, but try my edits and see how you go.

Comment: I have copied your code and included my original code after the comment that told me to do so. For some reason, it shows the product page very briefly, after which it redirects me to the actual php file (the one that is calculating the price). http://www.meulen.me/product.php?type=9

Comment: I think it is just my jQuery knowledge that is preventing this from working, but I have included the changes and this is the result: http://www.meulen.me/product.php?type=13

Comment: @meulendev, It's kind of hard to debug with minimal information. I have edited my answer, added your full code.

Answer (score 0):

You can register the blur() event on Quantity drop down ad then pus the results.
I have modified the script. Please see if it works for your implementation.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#quantityjquery").blur(function(){

    // Get some values from elements on the page:

      var size = $("#sizejquery").val();
      var paper = $("#paperjquery").val();
      var quantity = $("#quantityjquery").val();
      var url=$("#updatePrice").attr("action");

// Send the data using post

var posting = $.post(url, {
      size: size,
      paper: paper,
      quantity: quantity
    });

      // Put the results in a div

    posting.done(function(data) {
      var content = $(data).find("#content");
      $("#price").empty().append(content);
    });
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Call that method at document ready api in jquery as

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// your logic

});
```

### In terms of your code

```js
function fetchPrice(){
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $(this),
      size = $form.find("#sizejquery").val(),
      paper = $form.find("#paperjquery").val(),
      quantity = $form.find("#quantityjquery").val(),
      url = $form.attr("action");

    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post(url, {
      size: size,
      paper: paper,
      quantity: quantity
    });

    // Put the results in a div
    posting.done(function(data) {
      var content = $(data).find("#content");
      $("#price").empty().append(content);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    fetchPrice(); // calls as the page load complete
});
```

Hope it helps ..........

Comment: `var $form = $(this),` will try to construct a jQuery object using the `window` object. I'm not sure what the effects of that will be, but `url = $form.attr("action");` will certainly fail.

Comment: Thanks, but your code did not work for me! :/ When I tried it, it did not show the price, but instead showed nothing and made the placeholder price (0.00; this price normally gets replaced by the real price) disappear.